# iptables alternative for nat in windows

Tags: linux, windows, iptables, firewall, nat

When setting up a comms server I usually use iptables in linux to forward any incoming connections on a particular port to another server, e.g.

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:telnet to:x.x.x.x:23 

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

Does anyone know how to do this with windows?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install **RRAS**. Then you can follow the steps listed in [this page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469812.aspx).

Comment: I've had a pretty good attempt at this but it doesn't seem to work. Can I ask how sure are you that it provides a solution to the problem in question?

Comment: @James back in 2000 I used RRAS on Windows 2000 Advanced Server as a Lab's NAT Router, and it worked. Haven't touched RRAS since 2005, though, but it _should_ work.